How does WITH TABLOCK improve performance in full recovery model?
I'm doing some performance testing of a larger insert query (10 million rows).
In simple recovery model, the insert statement WITH (TABLOCK) takes 2 minutes to run.
This is because it will minimally log the transaction.
In full recovery model, if I don't use tablock then query takes 4 minutes. However if I use TABLOCK it takes 2 minutes. How is full recovery model able to achieve this speedup when it doesn't support minimally logged transaction?
The table doesn't have an index. If I do add an index then the load takes 2 minutes and 10 seconds. Still faster than the one without TABLOCK.
What is the cause of speedup in full recovery when performing inserts with tablock?

it doesn't support it does, in specific cases. Check Using INSERT INTO...SELECT to Bulk Import data with minimal logging and parallelism in the INSERT docs. In the full recovery model, minimal logging can work in heaps & columnstores

TABLOCK is used to prevent other connections from locking rows while your transaction inserts. It speeds things up because nothing else blocks your INSERT. It doesn't enable minimal logging by itself.

@PanagiotisKanavos - minimal logging isn't supported for full recovery model. I'm the only one working on this db so the speed improvement isn't due to blocking. I just added clustered index and tested there is 10 seconds additional it takes.

You may think you're the only one working on the database but a) the server doesn't know it so still has to lock every individual rows and b) there may be other applications running at the same time. A TABLOCK takes an exclusive lock on the table itself instead of individual pages or rows, something that automatically prevents other connections from using the table

Ah ok so then that's the primary reason for the insert finishing in half the time (even though fully logged), which is equal to the time taken for insert in the simple recovery model

Btw, i'm not sure if it matters, but did you actually have a proper full recovery mode on? Ie. you took a full backup after changing recovery model

Yes correct I verified that by taking log backups as well

The table-level lock might perform better because it incurs less overhead than acquiring and releasing many granular locks, but at the expense of concurrency.

@DanGuzman - it's a truncate and reload so I had expected it would escalate the lock to the table anyways. Surely there's something more to it that's improving the speed with TABLOCK in full recovery model

When doing some quick research about this, I found https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165659/benefits-of-using-with-tablock-on-an-insert ... the answer there suggests that it may also affect compression (using page compression vs row compression) and may also allow a parallel insert.
